# Ionic 3: Grey(?) horizontal bar under img

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

Ok so I have a horizontal bar at the bottom of my img, this is not part of the image, I tried cropping, changing from png to jpeg and changing dimensions, this is an excerpt from it's html

```html
<ion-content padding center text-center>
  <ion-img width="200" height="200" src="assets/imgs/applogo.png"></ion-img>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
```

and this is how it looks(sorry drew over the logo in red for privacy reasons): [image]

It may seem a simple issue but I found no one posting about it online, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the exact image dimensions on the `ion-img` element as mentioned in the official [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/)

The grey color appears because the `ion-img` component by default has a grey background color. You've set 200px as the height of your image but it is actually shorter than 200px so the background color of the ion-img element appears below the image.